# Ability to hide lines/columns in Google Charts using dataTable?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Firsty I'll point out that I have only been using JS and Charts for a few days so I'm probably completely missing something pretty obvious. I usually use PHP. Please assume I know NOTHING about JS !!!

I am trying to create a curve chart that plays startup animation when viewed by scrolling down the page, has the ability to hide lines if the user wants, and has custom tooltips giving extra information on each data point.

I currently have 2 versions of a page.
Version 1 (my original) uses dataTable, has the animation and tooltips but no ability to hide the lines.
Version 2 uses dataView instead, has the animation (by using an older version of google.charts.load) and the ability to hide lines, but no custom tooltips as the Google docs appear to say custom tooltips are for dataView ONLY.
Somehow I need to get all 3 requirements on 1 chart !

Version 1 can be found at: https://zoeballz.tv/wot/_Analyses/average_battle_duration_by_arty1.php
Version 2 can be found at: https://zoeballz.tv/wot/_Analyses/average_battle_duration_by_arty2.php

Version 1 Code:

```
let alreadyLoaded = false ;     
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if (alreadyLoaded === false){
        var element = document.querySelector('#triggerchart');
        var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
        // checking for partial visibility
            if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
                alreadyLoaded = true;
    
                google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            
                function drawChart() {
                    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Month');                 // Column 0
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', '0 Arty');                // Column 1
                    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); // Column 2
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', '1 Arty');                // Column 3
                    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); // Column 4
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', '2 Arty');                // Column 5
                    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); // Column 6
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', '3 Arty');                // Column 7
                    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); // Column 8
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', '4 Arty');                // Column 9
                    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); // Column 10
                    dataTable.addColumn('number', '5 Arty');                // Column 11
                    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}); // Column 12
                    dataTable.addRows([
                        <?php echo $chartdata; ?>
                    ]);

                    // Create the view table
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
//                  var view = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataTable);
                    view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,4]); // Set the columns to display

                    var options = {
                        title: 'World of Tanks - AVERAGE BATTLE DURATION - 2013 to 2023 by Number of Artillery in Battle - By Zoe Ballz',
                        curveType: 'function',
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                        hAxis: { title: 'Click on Legend below to highlight the lines' },
                        crosshair: { trigger: 'both' },
                        chartArea:{left: 100, top: 100, width: '88%', height: '65%' },
                        vAxis: {
                            ticks: [{v: 360, f: '6m 00s'}, {v: 390, f: '6m 30s'}, {v: 420, f: '7m 00s'}, {v: 450, f: '7m 30s'}, {v: 480, f: '8m 00s'}, {v: 510, f: '8m 30s'},
                                    {v: 540, f: '9m 00s'}, {v: 570, f: '9m 30s'}, {v: 600, f: '10m 00s'}
                            ]
                        },
                        animation: {
                            startup: true,
                            duration: 2000,
                            easing: 'inAndOut'
                        }
                    };
            
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
            
//                  chart.draw(view, options);
                    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Version 2 Code:

```
let alreadyLoaded = false ;     
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if (alreadyLoaded === false){
        var element = document.querySelector('#triggerchart');
        var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
            // checking for partial visibility
            if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
                alreadyLoaded = true;

                var chart, chartData, dataView;
                
                var columns = [
                    { type: 'string', label: 'Month' },
                    { type: 'number', label: '0 Arty', visible: true },
                    { type: 'number', label: '1 Arty', visible: true },
                    { type: 'number', label: '2 Arty', visible: true },
                    { type: 'number', label: '3 Arty', visible: true },
                    { type: 'number', label: '4 Arty', visible: true },
                    { type: 'number', label: '5 Arty', visible: true }
                ];
            
                var nullFunc = function() {return null;};
//              google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]}); // Original from page that hides lines (using dataView) https://codepen.io/gapple/pen/dyRmrL?editors=0110
//              google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}); // From MY original using dataTable - Cannot hide lines ? Animation works - Tooltips work
                google.charts.load('52', {'packages':['corechart']}); // Line hiding works - Animation works (give a.Ta error using "current")- No tooltips ?
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            
                function drawChart() {
                    if (!chart) {
                        chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                            ['Month', '0 Arty', '1 Arty', '2 Arty', '3 Arty', '4 Arty', '5 Arty'],
                            ['Jan 2023', 400, 500, 400, 470, 510, 410],
                            ['Feb 2023', 530, 360, 500, 570, 390, 510],
                            ['Mar 2023', 450, 500, 600, 470, 530, 500],
                            ['Apr 2023', 400, 400, 550, 440, 460, 500],
                            ['May 2023', 590, 600, 380, 510, 590, 380]
                        ], false);
                
                        dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(chartData);
                        chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                
                        // Toggle visibility of data series on click of legend.
                        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click',
                            function (target) {
                                if (target.targetID.match(/^legendentry#\d+$/)) {    
                                    var index = parseInt(target.targetID.slice(12)) + 1;
                                    columns[index].visible = !columns[index].visible;
                                    drawChart();
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
            
                    var visibleColumnIndexes = [0];
                    var colors = [];
            
                    for (var i = 1; i < columns.length; i++) {
                        if (columns[i].visible) {
                            colors.push(columns[i].color);
                            visibleColumnIndexes.push(i);
                        } else {
                            colors.push(columns[i].disabledColor);
                            visibleColumnIndexes.push({
                                calc: nullFunc,
                                type: columns[i].type,
                                label: columns[i].label,
                            });
                        }
                    };

                    var options = {
                        title: 'World of Tanks - AVERAGE BATTLE DURATION - 2013 to 2023 by Number of Artillery in Battle - By Zoe Ballz\nNOTE: Garbage data for testing',
                        curveType: 'function',
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                        hAxis: { title: 'Click on Legend below to SHOW/HIDE the lines' },
                        crosshair: { trigger: 'both' },
                        chartArea:{left: 100, top: 100, width: '88%', height: '65%' },
                        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                        vAxis: {
                            ticks: [{v: 360, f: '6m 00s'}, {v: 390, f: '6m 30s'}, {v: 420, f: '7m 00s'}, {v: 450, f: '7m 30s'}, {v: 480, f: '8m 00s'}, {v: 510, f: '8m 30s'},
                                    {v: 540, f: '9m 00s'}, {v: 570, f: '9m 30s'}, {v: 600, f: '10m 00s'}
                            ]
                        },
                        animation: {
                            startup: true,
                            duration: 2000,
                            easing: 'inAndOut'
                        },
                    };
                    dataView.setColumns(visibleColumnIndexes);
                    chart.draw(dataView, options);
                };
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Can anyone assist maybe, to either:

1. Get line hiding onto Version 1
2. Get Tooltips onto Version 2

or (and I aleady know how to do this).......

3. Use PHP to recreate dataTable in Version 1 from start and reload the page (not my preferred option but at least I know this will work !!)

(Whichever is easiest, although getting version 1 which uses dataTable and also uses the current release would probably be best I think !)

A possible alternative method to do this for option 2, may be for me to have a 2nd dataTable (as well as the original dataView) that could contain the tooltips, and use the addListener to display tooltips maybe ? No idea if that is possible.

Many thanks

Comment: there is a bug when using 'animation.startup = true' and a data view. if you want to have animation with the latest release, convert the data view to a data table during the draw method `chart.draw(dataView.toDataTable(), options)` -- as for adding tooltips and show / hide, you can add your tooltips as in version 1, but when adding your visible column indexes, simply add a second column index (+1) for the tooltip column.